# What is the purpose of a "True and CONDITION " inside the condition of a conditional statement?

Tags: python, if-statement, deep-learning

I was checking a deep learning python pytorch script and encountered a weird if statement.
A boolean True and another condition were bound together with an "and".
I couldn't figure out what it is suppose to do.

This is the code snippet(pretty lengthy function!):

```
 def read_data(self, data_dir):
        r"""Read the data from the dataset"""

        f = os.path.join(self.predata_dir, 'MH_01_easy.p')
        if True and os.path.exists(f):
            return

        print("Start read_data, be patient please")
        def set_path(seq):
            path_imu = os.path.join(data_dir, seq, "mav0", "imu0", "data.csv")
            path_gt = os.path.join(data_dir, seq, "mav0", "state_groundtruth_estimate0", "data.csv")
            return path_imu, path_gt
```

Because I am just exploring the code and the dataset is huge, I can't run the code.
But my guess is, it's redundant. Correct me if I'm wrong.
I would really appreciate your answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's redundant alright; `if True and foo` is equivalent to `if foo`.

Comment: Maybe there used to be another expression there and it was inlined to True.

Comment: Sometimes weird code is just weird.  The only way to really understand the purpose of that particular weirdness would be to ask the person who wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

It's redundant alright; `if True and foo` is equivalent to `if foo`. It's possible that that `True` had been something else and has been carelessly changed to `True`.

If it was `if True or foo`, I'd guess `True or` had been added as a temporary patch to make the condition always true, and then forgotten there.

Answer (score 0):

A similar and related usage would be `if True:` and `if False:` blocks used to selectively "turn on" or "turn off" portions of code during development, which is preferred by many to commenting out large blocks of code.

For instance, in my code for multi-processing GPU inference, I can't get a line-by-line debugger to step into the off-process inference. But I have a bug that occurs on frame 100 of a video as I process it each time. So I add a block that performs inference on a single GPU on-process. I want to run this block only on the problematic frame, and I want to be able to turn this block on and off selectively as the problem appears and disappears. I can easily use `if True and frame == 100:` to accomplish this, and then change to `False` after finding the issue. until I want to use this block of code again.